# Connect to Openvpn server through http proxy which has a dynamic ip

Tags: vpn, openvpn, http-proxy, client-server

My openvpn client will have to pass through a http proxy server before connecting to the openvpn server.

But the http proxy is on a dynamic ip.

From this tutorial - https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#connecting-to-an-openvpn-server-via-an-http-proxy

It seems to me that in the openvpn client script, i have to insert a public ip to reach the proxy. One way is to get a dynamic dns like this - https://account.dyn.com/

My question is - can i use a dns instead of an ip address in the Openvpn client script?
Ex -

```
http-proxy abc.dyndns.org stdin basic
```

Comment: Yes, [you can](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-0/).

Comment: You can use any IP address assigned to the HTTP proxy. If the OpenVPN client and HTTP proxy are on the same private network, you can use the private IP address of the proxy.